# discord.js bot can't clear specific text channels by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I know how to clear a text channel using

```
message.channel.bulkDelete()
```

But this requires me to get channel info from a message, since i will not be using a message i would like to be able to clear a text channel by it's id.
I have tried playing around with the classes and functions a bit but can't seem to find a solution.
How will I be able to achieve this?

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, to separate the question from your solution / answer. you can also accept it, if you are satisfied with your answer. Might be helpful for anyone in the future, who is looking for a question like this with a provided solution / accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the bot role permissions
Edit: The channel id should be a built-in function for discord.js
Also, go look at this: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#number-ranges

Comment: The permissions should be fine, the current problem is the bot clearing channels by id which I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: Yes, i have had this problem before.
I suggest looking online for a tutorial on how to do it.
There should be a built in code for the channel id on discord.js

Comment: I did make a command !clear and it works perfectly for clearing the channel u use it in, n ow I was thinking of making the bot use the command in the channels i need cleared but that doesnt work for some reason

Comment: Ok
By the way, maybe you can help me with my bot
my discord name is Ult!mate_CODER/ADMIN#4778
(ik that name cringe)

Answer (score 0):

So apparantly i figured it out by accident. U can get any channel by it's name or id and then clear it.

```
testChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "channel1");
testChannel.bulkDelete(100)
```